# Excel loses decimals on editing

Tags: excel, formatting

I have something weird happening to my excel data.

I have a list of times formatted like mm:ss,00 so 00:38,25 means 38 seconds and 250 milliseconds.

But when I select one of these cells, the formula bar displays 00:00:38 and if I want to edit to let's say 00:40,25 I can't because the ,25 just dissapears into the nether.

So what can I do so that the formula bar shows what is actually in the cell?

Here are some screens

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the time is displayed in the formula bar is controlled by your regional settings [customise > Time]. In my version of Excel, at least, I can change it to show AM or PM but I can't add milliseconds, so it may not be possible to display in the formula bar.

You can edit by just re-keying the new time value

Comment: Thank you for your answer I think it's plain stupid that the formula bar doesn't display the actual value of the cell.. I guess I'll just rekey it if I need to